# In C, my code to print the largest palindrome in a string is not printing the whole palindrome string?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I am doing an assignment that says to:
Find the largest palindrome in a string. A palindrome is a
sequence that reads the same backward as forward. racecar, eve, kayak are some examples.
My problem is that my string isn't printing the whole output. I am still pretty new at this so I don't know much but I think there's something wrong with printing. I will be really glad if someone could help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
int palindromelength(char *str, int i, int j);
char str[100];  
int main()
{
    int i,j,len,n;
    printf("Enter a string ");      
    fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);//takes user input
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;
    len=strlen(str);
    palindromelength(str, 0, len-1);//function call
    return 0;       
}
int palindromelength(char *str, int i, int j)//compare 
{       
    int len=strlen(str);
    i=0,j=len-1;//i starts from first letter and j starts from the last letter
    while(i<=j && j!=0)//edit:&& j!=0 because i=0->str[0] and j=0->str[0] is the same first letter
    {       
        if(str[i]==str[j])
        {           
            printf("%c%c\n",str[i],str[j]);//edit:added str[j] but it just prints a letter twice
            printf("if: i=%d j=%d str[i]=%c str[j]=%c\n",i,j,str[i],str[j]);/*edit:new                          
             printf to check the i and j values and the corresponding letters under if*/
            i++;//increment i
            j--;//decrement j               
        }           
        if(str[i]!=str[j])//if letters aren't same
        {
            printf("if: i=%d j=%d str[i]=%c str[j]=%c\n",i,j,str[i],str[j]);/*edit:new 
             printf to check the i and j values and the corresponding letters under the other if statement*/
            i=0;//i_initial?
            j--;//only decrement j              
        }
    }   
    return 0;   
}
```

```
output//edit to print the new printf statements
Enter a string abcbade //expected:abcba
length is 7
if: i=0 j=6 str[i]=a str[j]=e
if: i=0 j=5 str[i]=a str[j]=d
aa
if: i=0 j=4 str[i]=a str[j]=a
bb
if: i=1 j=3 str[i]=b str[j]=b
cc
if: i=2 j=2 str[i]=c str[j]=c
```

```
output 2:
Enter a string dabae   //expected:aba
length is 5
if: i=0 j=4 str[i]=d str[j]=e
if: i=0 j=3 str[i]=d str[j]=a
if: i=0 j=2 str[i]=d str[j]=b
if: i=0 j=1 str[i]=d str[j]=a
```

```
output 3:
Enter a string abcbacdcbaab //expected:abcba
length is 12
if: i=0 j=11 str[i]=a str[j]=b
aa
if: i=0 j=10 str[i]=a str[j]=a
if: i=1 j=9 str[i]=b str[j]=a
if: i=0 j=8 str[i]=a str[j]=b
if: i=0 j=7 str[i]=a str[j]=c
if: i=0 j=6 str[i]=a str[j]=d
if: i=0 j=5 str[i]=a str[j]=c
aa
if: i=0 j=4 str[i]=a str[j]=a
bb
if: i=1 j=3 str[i]=b str[j]=b
cc
if: i=2 j=2 str[i]=c str[j]=c
```

Comment: That is becase you are printing letters while finding out palindrome in palindromelength(). There are multiple ways, one approach is to find out the largest palindrome first and then print.

Comment: @MayurK I thought that was what I was doing? what would be the algorithm of what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

It is not printing complete palindrome because you have put your printf inside the check.

```
   if(str[i]==str[j])//if letters are same
    {           
        printf("%c",str[i]);//print palindrome letter
                            /*is there a way I can store all the palindrome 
                             characters in a string and print that string?*/
        i++;//increment i
        j--;//decrement j               
    }
```

As you can see, index "i" and "j" are part of the palindrome but you are printing only "i". So only first half of the palindrome will get printed.

Apart from this, I think you need to handle many other cases like there are multiple palindromes and you need to choose the largest one.
For example: `abcxyzyxdefabcdedcbaxyz`

So my suggestion is,

1) Implement a function which returns a largest palindrome from
    index i of the string, if present.

2) Call this function in a loop
    from index i=0 to length-2 of the original string.

3) Store the
    current largest palindrome index and length. Update it in each loop.

4) At the end, print the largest palindrome.

The function palindromelength() is doing the whatever I mentioned in step #1. But instead of printing the letters, you should return the length of the largest palindrome from it.

In main(), call palindromelength() in a loop with updated index as below.

```
for(i=0; i<(len-1); i++)
{
    palinrdomeLen = palindromelength(str, i, len-1);
    if(palinrdomeLen > largestPalindromeLen)
    {
        largestPalindromeLen = palinrdomeLen;
        largestPalindromeIdx = i;
    }
}
```

Apart from this in palindromelength(),

1) You need to update the function to return the length of the palindrome.

2) The search for palindrome should restart from index initial "i" when a `str[i]!=str[j]`.

```
if(str[i]!=str[j])//if letters aren't same
{
    i = i_initial; //i_initial is the "i" value passed to palindromelength()
    j--;//only decrement j              
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by i=i_initial. Since I am starting from 0 for this particular code i would mean 0 right?  in str[i]=str[j], if I print both of them it just prints the letters twice. I added printf statements in my original code to show the i and j values that gets printed. It's edited in my code here. Also thatnk you for pointing out about the palindrome length!

Comment: I mean at the beginning of palindromelength() save the original i value (int i_initial=i;) Whenever you find that str[i]!=str[j], you need to restart the search. For example, take this string and try to analyze the logic. - "abcbaxyzba" The output should be "abcba" right? See whether your function is returning it.

Comment: One more example: Assume string is "123abcbaxyzba". When i=3, the palindrome string should be "abcba". Is your current logic capable of finding this?

Comment: I did some more edits. Before finding the palindrome length I have to find the palindrome first right? but my code isn't even working right now. I understand what you mean by i_initial now. I can do that part but for now I am checking using small palindromes first. Thank you for explaining!

Comment: @serene Again you are porinting inside if statements. At that stage you are still in the process of searching palindrome and hence you may not be able to print properly. So one thing you can do. You can have a variable to store length of palindrome. In str[i]==str[j] case, increment length by 2 since two characters are part of palindorme, in  str[i]!=str[j] case reset length to zero. Outside while loop, print str[i_initial] to str[i_initial+length-1] characters. That is your palindrome.